# Why am I facing SSL issues in a production environment when using Chrome's Speculation Rules for prerendering?

Tags: google-chrome, preload, prerender

I'm attempting to use Chrome's Speculation Rules API to configure prerendering for my project. When I test this locally, it works successfully. However, when I deploy my project to the production environment, I encounter an issue. The preloading panel in Chrome displays the message "Preloading failed" with the failure reason being "The prerendering navigation failed because of an invalid SSL certificate."

I've ensured that my production environment has a valid SSL certificate and it's working as expected for other parts of the application. I'm not sure why the Speculation Rules API would be encountering this issue.

Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any insights on what might be causing this and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to use Chrome's Speculation Rules API to configure prerendering for my project. In my local development environment, the prerendering worked as expected, and I didn't encounter any issues.

However, when I deployed the project to the production environment, I started experiencing problems. Specifically, Chrome's preloading panel displayed the message "Preloading failed". The failure reason provided was "The prerendering navigation failed because of an invalid SSL certificate."

I expected the prerendering to work in the production environment just as it did in the local environment。

I'm currently at a loss as to why this issue is occurring and am seeking help to understand and resolve it.